# How to install MIT Photonic Bands software package on Debian

Tags: debian, terminal

How do I install the *MIT Photonic Bands* software package using Debian?

Comment: hi i'm sorry for my poor English and my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mpb
```